# Provide Typescript callback method to Facebook Login Button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm integrating Facebook login to my Angular7 application using Typescript. Using Facebook's Login Button plugin, I am able to login, but unable to properly provide a callback method to the button's data-onlogin attribute.

I have a typescript function defined in the same component as the login button, but the button is not picking up on it.

Note: I am also using [facebook-js-sdk type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/facebook-js-sdk/index.d.ts)

**login.component.html**

```html
<div 
  class="fb-login-button" 
  data-width="" 
  data-size="large" 
  data-button-type="login_with" 
  data-auto-logout-link="false"
  sdata-use-continue-as="false"
  data-onLogin="checkLoginStatus()"
>
</div>
```

**login.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

// The Facebook Javascript SDK
declare var FB: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    checkLoginStatus() {
        FB.checkLoginStatus((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<body>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: '{app-id}',
                autoLogAppEvents: true,
                xfbml: true,
                version: 'v3.3'
            });
        };
    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>

    <app-root></app-root>

</body>
```

ZoneJS is throwing an error in the console with:

Uncaught ReferenceError: checkLoginStatus is not defined

Comment: Please provide complete code, or set it up at Stackblitz.
Your class is missing the component decorator.

Comment: and what is `FB`, but as comment above, please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

to be accessible for FB plugin the method needs to be aliased on window object, this works for me:

```
ngOnInit() {
   window['checkLoginStatus'] = this.checkLoginStatus.bind(this);
}

checkLoginStatus(){
....
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.